# Ionic 2 add the local address to the remote address to contact

Tags: http, http-status-code-404, ionic2

My queries with Ionic 2 (2.0.0-beta.10) to a site outside back with a 404 :

> var url = 'https//api.mysite.fr/example;
>
> return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());

Response in chrome tool :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   url: "http://localhost:8100/https//api.mysite.fr/example"

How to not add the local execution url to the remote address to contact?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the **:** after the url *scheme*. It should be: `var url = 'https://api.mysite.fr/example;`